# WordPress - Shortcode is not rendering content on Gutenberg pages

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, elementor, wordpress-gutenberg

Platform users have the ability to post offers. These offers are displayed in a post table.

You can see the post table here - https://www.b2bmember.com/b2b-marketplace/

Post table is inserted with a shortcode: `[posts_table]`

There is a possibility to only display posts from a specific author by adding `author="x"` at the end (x= user id).

Example: `[posts_table author="x"]`

The goal is to display posts from each user on their profile page.

I need a solution where every user has a corresponding shortcode in their profile page automatically / programmatically.

To achieve this, I created a function that creates a shortcode which is the same post table shortcode but with the user/author id part at the end.

```
function authorid() {

$author_id = um_user('ID');
echo '[posts_table author="' . $author_id . '"]';
}

add_shortcode('user_offers', 'authorid');
```

This solution works when I add `[user_offers]` on a page that is built with Elementor page builder - a post table with corresponding author posts is successfully rendered.

However, It does not work if a page is built with Gutenberg. For Gutenberg pages it displays `[posts_table author="1"]`, 1 = user id depending on a profile page. So, the post table shortcode is generated correctly but nothing is rendering.

See a screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/K1YR7F7.png

I have tried to replace `echo` with `return`, but that does not fix the issue.

Why does it not work for pages that are built with Gutenberg / WordPress block editor?

Comment: Your shortcode function should be defined in a file like the active theme `functions.php` file. Where did you define/put your function? Also, even if changing `echo` to `return` didn't solve the issue, your function should return the output and not echo it, to avoid problems like invalid JSON response in the REST API.

Comment: @SallyCJ Shortcode function is added as a plugin. Please see a screenshot - https://pasteboard.co/K2gNtBV.png. I replaced `echo` with `return` - Thanks! Shortcode still doesn't work tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually noticed that your shortcode returns a shortcode tag (`[posts_table]`) instead of the shortcode output, so you should call [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) like so:

```php
return do_shortcode( '[posts_table author="' . $author_id . '"]' );
```

If you don't do that, then the default behavior in Gutenberg is that the `[posts_table]` is returned as-is instead of being parsed (e.g. replaced with a table HTML).

And despite that I *don't* use Elementor, the above code should work well in Elementor.

And keep in mind, shortcodes should always return the output and not echo it; otherwise, you'll likely get problems like invalid JSON response in the REST API (which for example, would then result in a failure saving a post through Gutenberg which uses the REST API).